# version of javascript in Domino Designer?

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

In working on a Domino web-based form, in the `onChange` event for a field (JavaScript), I am not able to use certain syntax, as it throws errors and the code will not save.  Examples are:

- instead of `var`, I would like to use `const` and `let`, but it will not take it.
- Also, when trying to use arrow functions it throws an invalid syntax error.

So does Designer come with a particular version of Javascript built in for compiling/syntax validation?    Is there a way to update that (patch or something on the Designer client?)

I am using HCL Domino Designer 11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's nothing you can do about the javascript syntax validation when editing JS in a form, but there is a workaround.

If you create a new File Resource in your database (under Resources->Files in the Applications pane), and give that resource a name ending with ".js", you can edit it in Designer with syntax highlighting but without validation, so you can use newer syntax.

Put functions in the File Resource for all your form logic, call those functions from events in the form, and also reference the File Resource in a `script` tag in the form header.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a rather lame explanation: Domino Designer doesn't really come with JavaScript, it has a JavaScript compiler that translates JavaScript to Java. It isn't the latest version of the language, that's for sure. More info on the HCL site: https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm/zh?id=community_question&sys_id=4299632fdb5e10d455f38d6d13961965

Comment: That's not correct. For use in forms Domino has its own JavaScript engine. As far as I know it is version 1.1 and more is not available in forms. If the form is rendered for the web noting gets compiled, the JavaScript is delivered as is to the browser. But that changes nothing for the forms designer. It only accepts very old JS

Comment: Oops I think I did it again. I *assumed* that Matt referred to JS in XPages (web-based, but server-side JS), but now I read the question again I think you're right. It must be because I gave up on using Notes forms in web-apps more than 10 years ago. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: yes you are right, this is not XPages....unfortunately I am tasked with maintaining a standard Domino traditional web design.   Thanks to all for verification.   I can use the older JS, it's rather simple stuff I need to do...hide <divs> ,populate fields, etc